# Distribute IOS app with cryptography inside US, non-crypto outside?

Tags: android, ios, cryptography, app-store-connect

To avoid the cryptographic export restrictions that are currently in place, can our app (that uses cryptographic methods) be sold 'only within the US', and a version of the app that has no encryption get sold 'everywhere else'?

Is this even possible with the current IOS and Android app stores?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns app distribution policies and not programming problems.

Comment: Just curious, how is this off-topic?  What in the heck even IS the topic?  After seeing literally thousands of non-programming related questions that have to do with prepping for various app-stores here on StackOverflow, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic -- easy to find via Google. You can check each store and see what restrictions are available there, for yourself. One reason such a question is off topic here, is because SO is meant to be a reference, and if anyone did your work of checking this for you, and copied the information here, this information may soon become outdated. This means the question/answer is no longer usable.

Comment: That's fine, but after pouring through all of the iTunesConnect policies and talking with two actual humans so far at Apple, they can't even answer the question yet.  So I'll keep looking elsewhere.

Comment: @323go I think the question is fine, it is not about distribution policies but about creating two versions of the app, one with and one without encryption.

Comment: @ChuckD With the exception of a few countries most common encryption can be exported. Additionally there are cryptographic methods that are not encryption and and certain uses that are exempted.

Comment: @Zaph interesting point. Chuck, can you confirm whether you're asking about how to build & maintain different app versions or how to distribute app versions you've already built? Or both?

Comment: The way I read the question as it stands, he's not asking how to create different versions of the app, but how to restrict their sale by country. The former would be trivial to learn with a quick search, while the latter is off-topic, unfortunately.

Comment: This had nothing to do with programming how-to's, which I guess is what the original complaint was about.  Rather, it has to do with export licenses, and whether it was possible that if I were to create a version of our app with major big-time encryption, could I release it without problem to the US market only, and release a completely open version outside of the US.  Trying to avoid getting lawyers and huge costs involved.  We had a legal quote of over 30K to just handle the legal issues of trying to export encryption in the first place.